# nodejs request.body returns empty object {}

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am using following code, request.body returns `{}` i would expect my output as `{username:"Mani",password:"pass"}` please help me to fix if anything wrong in this code sample.

### app.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
  response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

npm version:

express 4.14.0

body-parser 1.15.2

url http://localhost:3000/

method: POST

header: Content-Type: application/json

request payload : {username:"Mani",password:"pass"}

output of app.js console is {}

Comment: Try replacing with `app.use(bodyParser.text())` and tell us what the raw text content of the body is?

Comment: tried, didn't solve the issue. content which is passed from RESTClient is `{username:"Mani",password:"pass"}`

Comment: My suggestion was not to solve the issue, but figure out the problem. What is the data that the server is *receiving*? We know what you are sending, but what the server is receiving is more important.

Comment: @tcooc could you help me how to view raw text content, what method of request would give this information ?

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.text())` and your console output should show the text content.

Comment: am using app.use(bodyParser.text()) and find output below of `console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(request)) );`      


["_readableState","readable","domain","_events","_eventsCount","_maxListeners","socket","connection","httpVersionMajor","httpVersionMinor","httpVersion","complete","headers","rawHeaders","trailers","rawTrailers","upgrade","url","method","statusCode","statusMessage","client","_consuming","_dumped","next","baseUrl","originalUrl","_parsedUrl","params","query","res","body","route"]

Comment: Your request payload isn't valid JSON, are you sure that isn't the issue?

Comment: `{username:"Mani",password:"pass"}` Is not valid json, in case that is literally what you're sending. (I assumed you are sending it through javascript, which means it is being converted to json but it appears you're manually sending that based on the above comments)

Comment: yes it worked now, there were 2 issues that incorrect json and missing`app.use(bodyParser.text()) or app.use(bodyParser.json())`.
thanks @tcooc !

Comment: change  content-type to this content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: if using fetch don't forget to add a response.json() to decode first.  e.g. const data = { username: 'example' }
fetch('http://localhost:5000', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json)
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your body is a json document. You will need to configure body-parser to accept json:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: tried both `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());` but still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

try this, "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", must use this

```
 // chnage content-type to content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded 

 var settings = {
 "async": true,
 "crossDomain": true,
 "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 },
"data": {
"name": "mane"
} 
 }

 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
 console.log(response);
 });
```